# Can I change the background color where a sprite is shown in the inspector?

Tags: unity, sprites

this is how a sprite shows in the inspector.
It's white pixelart with transparent background.
Is there a way to change the background checkered pattern color in the inspector so I can actually see the sprite?

Note: I don't want to change any color in the game, just the background in the inspector, in the editor, so there's some contrast and I can actually see the sprite pattern.

[image]

Comment: I don't know if that's a feature. If you own pro though you can use the black theme which has a darker checkered pattern for the sprite inspector background.

Comment: @n_palum Yeah since I can't find anything similar, I guess it might not even be a feature.

Comment: As far as I could tell, pro version would be your only option but it doesn't sound like you need the pro version

Answer (score 2):

## Use a custom editor with sprite preview

**(EDIT: now supports multi-sprite images)**

1. Create an empty script (or use one you already got), let's call that `TestScript`.
2. Place this script on an empty game object.
3. Add a *Sprite Renderer* component to that object.
4. Add another script, let's name it `SpritePreview`. It should inherit from `Editor`. You can place the code for that class in the same file as the `TestScript`.

**SpritePreview**

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(TestScript))]
public class SpritePreview : Editor {
    public override void OnInspectorGUI() {
    var sr = ((TestScript)target).GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();

    // it's not enough to check for the renderer as it might be empty
    if (sr && sr.sprite) {

        // we need the rect in pixels to reserve space in the layout system
        // we also use it for calculating the rect in percentage
        var rect = sr.sprite.rect;

        // reserve a rect in the layout of the editor, we will draw the sprite there
        var destRect = GUILayoutUtility.GetRect(rect.width, rect.height);

        // the texture, this object contains all of the sprites in case of a multiple sprites image
        var texture = sr.sprite.texture;

        // calculate the rect of the selected sprite as a percentage of the sprite sheet
        // this is how TexCoords work
        var rectAsPercentage = new Rect(rect.x / texture.width, rect.y / texture.height,
                               rect.width / texture.width, rect.height / texture.height);

        // draw the selected sprite
        GUI.DrawTextureWithTexCoords(destRect, texture, rectAsPercentage);
    }
    }
}
```

5. Now select a sprite in the sprite renderer.
6. You will see the preview in the editor, with grey background, like this:
   [image: Result]

### EDIT: i've updated the script to also work with multiple sprite resources:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, looks like a great solution and a good introduction on extending the editor! Will try this.

Comment: Please mark answer as accepted if this works for you :-)

Comment: Count on it, as soon as I make myself some time to work with unity. Despite what I'd like, PHP is still paying my bills instead of Unity.

Comment: I tried it, it does work but it displays the complete spritesheet, I already have that on the project view. I'd need to see the individual sprites in order to be able to select them. See the attached screenshot in my question.

Comment: Try with the new code ;-)

Comment: Ok, kind of works, but it displays the sprite once I selected it. The idea is that I can see all the sprites in the spritesheet so I know which one to select. Once I select it, I can also see it in the scene view.
Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You can change texture type to advanced and uncheck Alpha Is Transparency checkbox. It still behaves as Sprite in the game as far as I tried, though be careful about other values and read about them before changing. Sprite still has transparency in the scene and the game views.

[image: Alpha is not transparency]

Comment: I don't have Advanced as an option for texture type, but I de have "Alpha is transparency", I unchecked it, it doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean, you must have it. It's in Unity, check out documentation. Just pick the texture or sprite in project folder and it's on the top, Texture Type - Advanced is last in the list.